# Threading or Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading

I have some code that I am trying to accelerate.  My goal is to download and save about a million files.  I am using the requests library to access the content. I am more confused then ever.  Most of the Q/A suggest that the proper method is to use the threading module when a task is I/O bound and since I am connecting to a server, waiting for a response and then writing the response to disk my task is I/O bound.

But then I read something like this

Multiple threads can exist in a single process. The threads that belong to the same process share the same memory area (can read from and write to the very same variables, and can interfere with one another).

my code goes something like this - before threading

```
def create_list(some_ftp_site):
    # do some stuff to compare the list to
    #  the last list  and return the difference in the two

    return list_to_pull


def download_and save_the_file(some_url):
   thestring = requests.get(some_url).content
   file_ref = open(something)
   fileref.write(the_string)
   fileref.close()


if __name__ == '__main__'
   files_to_get = create_list(some_ftp_site)
   if len(files_to_get) != 0:
       for file_to_get in files_to_get:
           download_and_save(file_to_get)
```

Using either is a jump into the deep-end for me.  Thus, if I multithread this I am afraid that I could have something unexpected happen for example the first half of some file concatenated to the second half of another.

Is this type of task better suited for multiprocessing or multithreading.  Clearly I am not going to know if two different file parts are concatenated because they written to the same variable

Comment: multithreading is only dangerous if the threads share variables. If you're just passing in a list of URL's to each of them to download, it is perfectly safe to download them both in parallel

Comment: Is it not possible that using an existing program to do this kind of task would be the best idea?

Comment: 'and can interfere with one another' - put another way, 'can actually communicate easily with each other'.  More threading FUD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading can get messy and require varible locking through mutexes. Your applications seems fit for multiprocessing which is simple to implement. Take your code and put it in a method say:

```
def download_and_save_the_file(some_url):
    thestring = requests.get(some_url).content
    #Make sure you create unique names
    something = unique_filename(some_url)
    file_ref = open(something)
    fileref.write(the_string)
    fileref.close()
```

Then create a pool using multiprocessing and a list of URL's, The parallel download will proceed as:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,cpu_count

p = Pool(cpu_count()-1)
p.map(download_and_save_the_file,files_to_get)
```

Comment: This is just a copy from the OP's pseudopython. Edited in case it is offending you.

Answer (score 4):

Either will work, but multiprocessing will be safer and perhaps easier to implement.  Keep in mind that for Python in particular, the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) means that multiple threads won't get much benefit from multiple cores, whereas with multiprocessing that's not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are building an IO bound app most of your app will remain in a blocked state while your data is downloading.  This is true whether you use threading or multi-processing.  If you really want to download some serious data use a concurrent framework like gevent for python.  There are others, but this framework will allow you to do your IO calls in a non-blocking state.  In other words, it is designed for exactly this kind of application with this kind of load.

If you go the threading route you will be eventually hit a wall with how many threads you can create.

The same is true for how many processes you can run in parallel.

With using gevent for example you can create thousands upon thousands of "greened" threads because they are so cheap to create.

http://www.gevent.org

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *accelerate* your application then you'll have to go with multi processing, not multi threading. The GIL in Python means that threads aren't wholly independent paths of execution like one is used to in other languages. If you're going to be running a lot of processes you may wish to consider which OS you host your Python on; inter process context switch times in Windows aren't especially fast.

As with any multi process / multi thread application it will be necessary to ensure that each process or thread is doing a sensible amount of work, otherwise your application will be all context switching and less actual running...